# How to get data from below service?

Tags: angular

This is the service given for me

```
GET /part-usage-logs/details/v1/{objectId}/{identifier}
```

**objectId: is either swad Id or swHwTemplate Id
identifier: is either ‘swad’ or ‘swHwTemplate’**

How do I register and call this service to get data in console.

Comment: You can create a function in service and call this service function from angular component and console the response.

Comment: import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient)
this.http.request("get", url_, options).subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
    })

Comment: Please provide context. What does you code look like? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not a service, this is a HTTP route.

Second, if you would show us some code we would make better answers.

According to your "post", I could say :

1. Type in terminal `ng g s usageLog` To generate a service called usageLogService.

   -> Into this new service, write something like

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpParams, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class usageLogService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDetails(objectId: any, identifier: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${environment.api}/part-usage-logs/details/v1/${objectId}/${identifier}`);
  }

}
```

2.Make a dependancy injection into the component you want to use this service like

```js
constructor(private usageLogs: usageLogService) {
    // Put the good objectId and identifier
    this.usageLogs.getDetails(2, 5).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Comment: { 
"swadId":"01080",
"swHwTemplateId":null,
"createdBy":"johnschacko@gmail.com",
"createdOn":"2019-10-22 12:39:40.0",
"basePartNumber":"18C865",
"ecuName":"Audio Control Module",
"partDetails":[ 
{ 
"partType":"Final Assembly",
"partD1d":null,
"partDescription":"",
"basepartNumber":null,
"partNumber":null
},

Comment: This is what you get by `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

create your-file-name.service.ts

```
1. Use below imports to implement Http Service (SomeService)

import { HttpClient}  from '@angular/common/http';

2. Create instance for HttpClient

constructor(private _httpSvc: HttpClient) {}

3. implementing get method  

      getDetails() {
         this._httpSvc.get(`/part-usage-logs/details/v1/${objectId}/${identifier}`)

      }
```

* Component Code

```
constructor(private _SS: SomeService)
details() {
   this._SS.getDetails().subscribe(res=> console.log(res));
}
```